# UWP drag and drop from WebView onto Canvas

Tags: c#, canvas, webview, uwp

I tried this code. I drag Image from WebView to Canvas. But nothing to be show. Maybe dropped data is URL or html data. BUt I don't know how to convert html data to Bitmap data.

```
private async void drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
    {
        var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
        if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                Point drop = e.GetPosition(Board);
                var storageFile = items[0] as StorageFile;
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));

                Image img = new Image();
                img.Source = bitmapImage;
                img.Width = 200;
                img.Height = 150;
                Canvas.SetLeft(img, drop.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(img, drop.Y);
                Board.Children.Add(img);
            }
    }
}
```

XAML is below.

```
<WebView x:Name="WebView" Source="https://google.com" ScriptNotify="Notify" NavigationCompleted="Completed" ></WebView>
<Canvas AllowDrop="True" DragOver="dragOver" Drop="drop"></Canvas>
```

Comment: By testing on my side, drag an image from Webview to Canvas will not trigger the drop event of Canvas. Could you please show me where you invoke this method and the XAML code snippet?

Comment: Thank you. I add XAML code.

Comment: Where is the webview control? Or you mean drag from browser?

Comment: I'm sorry. I add webView control. Maybe it is not impossible. So I try another way. Check this Topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984856/how-to-get-dragover-image-from-webview-to-bitmap-uwp-c?noredirect=1#comment78931966_45984856