# How to get dragover image from webView to Bitmap (UWP C#)

Tags: c#, image, xaml, webview, uwp

I want to drag&drop image on website to Canvas on Xaml.
But it is not acceptable, because dragged data is not image data but html data.
So I try to get dragover thumbnail image.
But I don't know how to access dragover thumbnail image.

How can I access dragover thumbnail image. I want to know those code. C#.

--Xaml--

```
    <WebView x:Name="WebView" Source="https://google.com" ScriptNotify="Notify" NavigationCompleted="Completed" ></WebView>
    <Canvas x:Name="Board" AllowDrop="True" DragOver="dragOver" Drop="drop" Background="White"></Canvas>
```

--C#--

```
    private void dragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
        e.DragUIOverride.IsContentVisible = true; // I want to get this content data. To bitmap.
    }
```

Comment: Can you include a sample "html data"?

Comment: I add sample code. But it is not "html data" but "Xaml data".

Comment: While dragging you automatically get thumbnail image. I think I didn't understand your request.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to convert thumbnail image to bitmap image. For pasting on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the `BitmapImage` from `DragEventArgs`

```
if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
{
    try
    {
        var a = await e.DataView.GetBitmapAsync();
        var c = await a.OpenReadAsync();
        BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
        b.SetSource(c);
        MyCanvasImage.Source = b;
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't this way. Thumnail image from webView is not "StandardDataFormats.Bitmap". So this code does not run... May be thumbnail image from webView is "StandardDataFormats.Html". But I can't convert "standardDataFormats.html" to Bitmap image...

Comment: @Tarou Can you include a sample "html" in your post?

Comment: Thank you Vijay for every times. I use web site of Google.com. So it is no sample "HTML" data. I drag image from search results of google on webView to canvas. I drag image, but it becomes URL data. For example, I drag image to Desktop, dropped data becomes link. So "StandardDataFormats.Bitmap" does not work. May be browser is Edge. And webView engine is Edge too.

Comment: @Tarou Do you mean image search in Google?

Comment: Yes, I mean image search in Google or some images on other web site.